# UWP App Extensions

Tags: c#, win-universal-app

I want to create an UWP App, that consumes plugins.

While it sounds promising, [`Windows.ApplicationModel.AppExtensions`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.appextensions.appextension.aspx) seems to be "useless" for this task. Unless everything my extension needs to provide are some files or key value pairs, but no Logic (unless it is provided via scripts as strings or files).

Is this observation correct, or did I miss something.

Comment: It depends on what you're looking at doing. AppExtensions are meant to be a very basic extension to your application. For example, you have a photo editing app and you'd create an extension that exposes a feature for converting the picture to greyscale. It has been designed as a service for your application that you talk to, basically an app-to-app comm scenario.

Comment: `AppExtensions` is to used to provide information about an application extension. Seems you'd like to add plugins from code behind or something? Please specify what plugins would you like to add, see if we can offer a help on that.

Comment: @GraceFeng-MSFT I want to create Pluggins for my app that analize music and return the Results. The music should be transmitted to the plugin as file location and returns an array of results (asynchronosly). Those results are poco with DataContracts and capsule only some timing information. I currently prototyping the functionallity using MEF. But as far as I know this will not work in a Production UWP App.

Comment: @JamesCroft92 I will look into App Services. Thanks :)

Comment: @lokimidgard there was a great session at BUILD this year that covered the topic of app extensions. I'd recommend it (https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2016/B808)

Comment: @lokimidgard For what you're looking at in terms of MEF style dynamic loading of views and code, this is not possible in UWP currently

Comment: I hope I can look in to it on the weekend. I plan to use App Services to send strings that contains serelized parameter and serelized return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like commenters already said, what I searched was not available in the standard Windows API.

I had also no luck in finding some Framework what would already had done what I needed.

---

In the end I wrote something myself: Not AppExtension, not AppService but [AppPlugin](https://github.com/LokiMidgard/AppPlugin) (using both Extensions and Service).

It is not perfect but enough for my purposes.

---

Thank you for the comments (especially for the video)